# images are not displayed properly

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app which displays images and text using a lazylist.

I get data from `json` from the server. When I enter some data and path to images manually into mysql database then those images are displayed properly in the app.

But when I take an image from the mobile camera and upload that image, it inserts the path properly in the mysql database but it does not shown in my app.

Can someone tell me why am I having this problem? I do not get an error in my logcat.

Has someone else had this problem? If yes then how did you solve it? Please help me.

---

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_list);

    inboxList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    List<String> profile_photo = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> userName = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> place = new ArrayList<String>();

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    //adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, tS, mTitles);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    /********************************/

    JSONObject json = userFunctions.homeData();

    Log.e("Data", json.toString());

    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
    // Log.d("Inbox JSON: ", json.toString());

    try {
        data = json.getJSONArray("data");
        Log.d("inbox array: ", data.toString());
        // looping through All messages
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String uid = c.getString("uid");
            String name = c.getString("name");
            String success = c.getString("success");
            String profile_img = c.getString("profile_photo");
            //String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

            JSONObject places = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PLACES);
            String place_photo = places.getString(TAG_PLACE_IMG);

            Log.e("place_photo", place_photo);
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put("uid", uid);
            map.put("name", name);
            map.put("success", success);
            map.put("profile_image", profile_img);

            profile_photo.add(profile_img);
            userName.add(name);
            place.add(place_photo);
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            inboxList.add(map);
        }

        profile_image = new String[profile_photo.size()];
        user_name = new String[userName.size()];
        place_image = new String[(place.size())];

        profile_photo.toArray(profile_image);
        userName.toArray(user_name);
        place.toArray(place_image);
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, profile_image, user_name, place_image);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*******************************/
}
```

---

**Here is lazy adapter class**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private String[] name;
private String[] place_photo;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d, String[] username, String[] place_image) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    name = username;
    place_photo = place_image;
    //Log.e("path", d.toString());
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_list_item, null);

    //TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.username);
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
    ImageView place=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.place);
    //text.setText("item "+position);
    title.setText(name[position]);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(place_photo[position], place);
    return vi;
}
}
```

Comment: @omidnazifi I added a couple of files above. Please check them

Comment: does this problem persist after device reboot. I mean did you try, 1. Capture camera image, save in db, reboot device and then see, if images are being displayed or not

Comment: Could you clarify, do you store images in db or paths to the images which are on sd card? How do you store images, as Base64 strings? What is `imageLoader` and what `DisplayImage` do?

Comment: Can you show image path (for image from camera) which you save to DB?

Comment: Please provide examples of the "manually-entered" path into your database plus the one that your application generates (which does not work). Also, where do the files actually live?

Comment: How big are the mobile camera photos you're uploading? Byte size and pixel dimensions please.  I only ask since Android ImageView has a texture size limit so if the images are too big then they're likely to not show up.  Size limits are usually 2048x2048 but it all depends on your device's OpenGL implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I take image from mobile camera and upload that image, it does insert all the path properly in mysql database but it is still not shown in my app

Are the URLs of the new Image and old Image the same?

If so then it may be the case of Image cache. The ImageLoader caches the image using the URL as the key.... Try again after clearing the App data.

Comment: you can clear it manually...(Settings > Apps > yourApp > Clear cache)but if it solve the problem then you need to change your webservice so that update images should have different URLs...

Comment: Well it has same url but different images name. I mean one image url is `http://example.com/appname/photos/useridfolder/image1.jpg` and second image url is `http://example.com/appname/photos/useridfolder/image2.jpg`. Do you think it is same url?